# TIdHTTP returns "Socket Error # 10060'#$D#$A'Connection timed out."

Tags: sockets, delphi, ssl, delphi-xe5, idhttp

I'm new to Delphi. To communicate with WebService, I added two components, TIdHTTP and TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL for SSL(https). When getting response from server, it doesn't work and returns "Socket Error # 10060'#$D#$A'Connection timed out." What should i do? below is my code.

```
procedure TForm1.btnRequestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  lIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

begin
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  lIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  try
    lHTTP.IOHandler := lIOHandler;
    lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    s := lHTTP.Get('https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/');
    Memo.Text := s;
  finally
    lHTTP.Free;
    lIOHandler.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed works fine as-is when I try it in the latest version of Indy.  The returned `String` contains the site's HTML, as expected.

Indy uses infinite timeouts for its `ConnectTimeout` and `ReadTimeout` properties by default, so the only way you can be getting that error is if the OS itself is timing out when trying to connect to the server.  Make sure your machine has a network route to reach `esta.cbp.dhs.gov`.  Can you load the URL in a web browser?

Comment: Yes! I'm able to connect the URL, I gonna check company's network policy or something else. If it's a network problem, what kind of things shoud i check?

Comment: If a web browser can connect to the site, there is no reason TIdHTTP should not be able to connect, either.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error, with Indy 10.5.7. Actually the error happens as soon as i call the GET command.

Comment: @delphirules like I said, it works fine for me using the latest version (which is currently 10.6.2.5457).  10.5.7 is a very outdated version, please consider upgrading.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Where can i update ? Is this version compatible with Delphi 2007 ? Thanks !

Comment: @RemyLebeau I updated, but now i get this error : 'Error connecting with SSL.
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure'. Any hints, please ? :)

Comment: @delphirules There is no way to know without seeing your code and the actual handshake back and forth. But that is a topic for another question, it doesn't belong on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message. I have Indy-10.1.5 and Delphi-7, Win-7x64 and SSL dlls from indy_OpenSSL096m.zip. My problem was when I use some really slow web-sites. Those sites even in Google Ghrome sometimes not working, it says "this page is not available" - instead. Other sites work fine.